# Looking for django "prototypes" ("blog", "forum", "issue-tracker", "wiki", etc.)

Tags: django

I don't know much about web development, so probably this question will sound exceptionally clueless...

Anyway, I'm starting out with Django.  I figure that by now there must be fairly standard Django patterns for "canonical" website types, e.g., "a blog", "a forum", "a store", "a wiki", "an issue tracker", etc.  I.e., off-the-shelf, "base" implementations (using Django) that, with a modicum of customization, would be adequate for most users requiring a website of such types.

By this I mean that, for example, most forums could be *passably* implemented by just customizing a relatively small number of parameters in the "canonical" Django-based forum.  Likewise for the other website "types" ("blog", "issue tracker", etc.).

(I would like to call these prototypes something like "website templates", but in this context the term "template" is already taken.  But really, this is all I'm talking about: "templates" for entire Django-based implementations of various website "types".)

> Is there such a collection of "Django prototypes"?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMHO

http://www.djangopackages.com/ as "main" place for packages

and

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/misc/design-philosophies/ as main philosophi for django devs

And prefer not thinking about any blocks of code like "template".

Read some code, get idea from it, then write own code. Try to avoid copy-paste strategy :)

And don't forgot about python pep